# Cakephp SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, find

I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set_origin' at
>   line 1

this error occur when I add this line in my OrderItems controller.

```
$products = $this->OrderItem->Product->find('all');
```

and I have no idea what to change.

if i try `$products = $this->OrderItem->Product->find('list');`, the error gone. but i need to use find('all') method.

Can anyone help me. thanks in advance.

**SET ORIGIN**

1. APP\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php line 218 → Model->__call(string, array)

   'set_origin'
   array(
       (int) 0 => (int) 1
   )

2.APP\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php line 218 → Style->set_origin(integer)

```
    else
      $this->_styles[$key] = clone $style;

    $this->_styles[$key]->set_origin( $this->_current_origin );

  }
```

**pdf/default.ctp**

```
<?php  
require_once(APP . 'Vendor' . DS . 'dompdf' . DS . 'dompdf_config.inc.php'); 
spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload'); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->set_paper = 'A4';
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "landscape");
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($content_for_layout), Configure::read('App.encoding'));
$dompdf->render();
echo $dompdf->output();
```

**ERROR.LOG**

```
2014-02-03 09:29:17 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set_origin' at line 1
Request URL: /mall/orderItems/receipt_pdf/201.pdf
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(460): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(426): DboSource->_execute('set_origin', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(666): DboSource->execute('set_origin', Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(611): DboSource->fetchAll('set_origin', Array, Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(799): DboSource->query('set_origin', Array, Object(Style))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php(218): Model->__call('set_origin', Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php(218): Style->set_origin(1)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php(1340): Stylesheet->add_style('html', Object(Style))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php(1077): Stylesheet->_parse_sections('html { ?  displ...')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php(307): Stylesheet->_parse_css('/**? * dompdf d...')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\dompdf.cls.php(535): Stylesheet->load_css_file('C:/xampp/htdocs...', 1)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\Vendor\dompdf\include\dompdf.cls.php(696): DOMPDF->_process_html()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\View\Layouts\pdf\default.ctp(8): DOMPDF->render()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\View\View.php(945): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\View\View.php(907): View->_evaluate('C:\xampp\htdocs...', Array)
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\View\View.php(535): View->_render('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\View\View.php(479): View->renderLayout('', 'default')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(952): View->render(NULL, NULL)
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(194): Controller->render()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(OrderItemsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\mall\app\webroot\index.php(110): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#21 {main}
```

OrderItem model look like this:

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * OrderItem Model
 *
 * @property Order $Order
 * @property Product $Product
 */
class OrderItem extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'id';


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Order' => array(
            'className' => 'Order',
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: can you paste (some of) the content of the `OrderItem` model?

Comment: You might have missed a closing parenthesis or something. Just print the Query.

Comment: @cornelb i already update my question. i put the content of OrderItem model.

Comment: @JensonMJohn hi, sorry i still new in cakephp. what do u means by print the query?

Comment: @user3073725 http://blog.tersmitten.nl/how-to-debug-sql-from-a-controller-in-cakephp.html

Comment: I wanted to see if you have any $model->set_origin() calls somewhere in the code. Can you search for `set_origin` and see if your models use that in any way?

Comment: @cornelb i found it in APP\Vendor\dompdf\include\stylesheet.cls.php.
i use dompdf to view pdf.

Comment: can you paste the code from that file which is related to `set_origin`?

Comment: @cornelb I already update it in my question.

Comment: check error logs, there ius something wrong with the query.try this  $log = $this->OrderItem->Product->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);       
debug($log); and find query.

Comment: hi @Anubhav.
it show this line:
array(
 'log' => array(),
 'count' => (int) 0,
 'time' => null
)
I already edit my question. the error.log.

Comment: Try this $this->OrderItem->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false); debug($log);

Comment: @Anubhav got same debug:
array(
 'log' => array(),
 'count' => (int) 0,
 'time' => null
)

Comment: can you paste the code that calls the DOMPDF function? (from the controller)

Comment: at controller, i add:
1.public $components = array('RequestHandler');
2.public function receipt($ordid = null) {
$products = $this->OrderItem->Product->find('all');
  // increase memory limit in PHP 
  ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
  $this->set('orderItem', $this->OrderItem->read(null, $ordid));
$this->set(compact('products'));
 }
@cornelb

Comment: @cornelb also i add in pdf/default.ctp:
as i update in my question

Comment: can you try to use `find('all')`, but specify the columns you need?

Comment: @cornelb I try: $products = $this->OrderItem->Product->find('all', array('fields' => array('Product.brand_id')));
but still got the same error :(

Comment: can you comment the part related to dompdf from the view, make sure the query works, then uncomment them one by one, to see where it breaks?

Comment: Please always mention the exact software versions you are using (CakePHP, DOMPDF)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is most probably a naming conflict, where a class name used in the DOMPDF context is identical to one of your already loaded model classes, judging from the stacktrace and the DOMPDF code, this would be a class called `Style`.

The fact that the problem only appears when using `find('all')`, indicates that the problematic model class is somehow related to your `Product` or `Order` model (or maybe there are even associations in the `AppModel` class?), because `find('list')` explicitly excludes relations (by using `recursive = -1`).

In case you do not have a model class named `Style`, debug the type of `$this->_styles[$key]` to figure the exact classname, and then resolve the conflict by renaming the model or the style class (if possible).

Comment: yes you are right..i got a model name style. after i change the class name, the error gone. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.I have cakephp 2.4.6 version.My local is xampp but server is lampp.I used lower case of all my model class.Such as app/Model/student.php, app/Model/group.php, app/Model/order.php, app/Model/list.php.

When ever I use $this->Model->methodName(); inside my controller,it works fine in my local but gives such "Cakephp SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064" in server.

As Linux is case sensitive,hence it was unable to create database object with the lowercase model name.Hence it gave PDO related error.

I changed the model names with 1stletter Upper such as below
app/Model/Student.php,app/Model/Group.php, app/Model/Order.php, app/Model/List.php.

And my problem was solved.

Plz give feedback if ur problem persist after following the above.